# How to get time difference from cells formatted as dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, date-time

I have two columns of dates and times, formatted as Custom `dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm`.

A third column is `=C3-B3`, `=D3-D3`, `=x3-x3`, etc.

[image: excel cells]

As you can see, it does not tell the difference in days, hours and minutes, as I would like, but shows the difference in a date format, with the days, hours and minutes being correct, but with January 1900 added for some weird reason.

How would I get a result with just the difference in days, hours and minutes?

---

I originally added a link to an example file [**HERE**](https://1drv.ms/x/s!Ap6pXz3yzwb_nKQbqDtNhfmqZ2YPuA), but I noticed that when I open the link in Incognito Mode, to make sure that it was Public, I noticed that it turns the dates into `mm/dd/yyyy` format, which is really stupid and even more confusing.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

[image]
*Write this formula in cell D3 and fill down as necessary.*

```
=INT(C3-B3)&" Days "&HOUR(MOD(C3-B3,1))&" Hour "&MINUTE(MOD(C3-B3,1))&" Minutes"
```

*I hope this helps.*

Comment: Thanks for your help, but the other answer gave exactly the same results with a little modification and as it is much more simple for me to understand.

Comment: Actually, your results of 31 Days and 61 Days were not correct, but I don't understand the formula to say why.

Comment: 31 Days is the difference between 01/02 and 01/01 also 61 Days is between 01/08 and 01/06 ,,,, you can count the difference even on fingers.

Comment: The first four rows use my original UK date format (dd/mm/yyyy), but the next six rows use the US (mm/dd/yyyy) format and the last two use the UK format again, but with a different separator.  Making these sorts of mistakes results in a big mess in your calculations!

Comment: @paradroid,, Check the Screen Shot, I've applied UK Format to both Date Columns as you did and for your knowledge Date Format doesn't effects the Calculation, the Formula I've suggested is Technically a correct method to find the difference in Days ,, Hours and Minutes.

Comment: The Solution suggested by Mcalex to apply the Format d:hh:mm to Column C is not enough, unless you not apply to Column D also and finally it looks like a TIME, like 1:16:38,, quite confusing even sounds easier!!

Comment: Rajesh, you are not using UK format on six of the rows. Five of the rows include dates which have not even happened yet if they are supposed to be in UK format.  Compare with my original screenshot. Using the Custom format `d "days," h "hrs" mm "mins"` gives the correct times for my service charge invoice in a readable format.

Comment: The formula for this answer does come up with the correct values and is the correct answer, but the data in the example tables is not the same as mine (and therefore the results are incorrect).

Comment: @paradroid,, then better you change and test your data,,,.

Answer (score 1):

Change the cell format in Column C to custom.

In the custom format box type:  `d:hh:mm`

This should produce the desired result.

**EDIT:**

Would ya look at that?  Excel has a ['DATEDIF'](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/datedif-function-25dba1a4-2812-480b-84dd-8b32a451b35c) function.  Syntax:

```
=DATEDIF(Date1, Date2, Interval)
```

According to [Chip Pearson](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/datedif.aspx), this was documented once, in Excel 2000, but has been in Excel since '95 and is treated like other Formulae's drunk cousin (ie Excel knows it lives a happy and useful life, but will not speak of it in polite conversation.)

There are some examples on the link above showing how to list differing date components in the result.  It doesn't appear to deal with time, however.

Comment: Thanks, that was an easier solution to what I was expecting.  I used `d "days," h "hrs" mm "mins"` to get the result I wanted.

Comment: If you apply the Custom Format as you suggested d:hh:mm, Date & Time Value in Column C of C3 will looks like 20:12:06 and after you Subtract C3 to B3 and apply the same Format d:hh:mm you get 1:16:38. This you mean as 1day 16Hrs 38Minutes,, which actually looks like a Time 1:16:38.

Comment: @RajeshS I thought the same, but it gave the correct results and I modified it to be more readable, as my previous comment explains.

Comment: This only works if the number of days does not exceed 31, after that it will restart at 1.  the `d` does not return the number of days but the day of the month.

Comment: DATEDIF formula finds the difference in Year, Month and Days but the OP demands to find difference in days, hours and minutes!!